# Mysql event schedule run evry month

Tags: mysql, events

```
DELIMITER $$

ALTER DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` EVENT `update_start_date` ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MONTH 
DO 

UPDATE categories SET start_date=now() where status = 1 $$

DELIMITER ;
```

The above event runs only one time at the month beginning but next month begining not run, Le me know how run event every month begining.

Comment: You're doing wrong thing. To schedule something - you will need to use scheduler - that will be `cron` for *nix and `AT` for Windows

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use "cron" for this

Answer (score 0):

I would personally advise that you use cron or some other external schedule management system.

IF you must to mySQL to handle schedules:

```
DELIMITER $$

ALTER DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` EVENT `update_start_date` ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MONTH START NOW()
DO 

UPDATE categories SET start_date=now() where status = 1 $$
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html for more details, but here is a simple version.

First you need to enabled the scheduler ->

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

and then schedule the actual thing

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS event_name ON SCHEDULE EVERY MONTH
STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 DAY 
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
ENABLE 
COMMENT 'comment'
DO BEGIN
  //SQL statements here.
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Please note, that this requires superuser access to your MySQL database (CRON would require super user access to the server ! )

Comment: Error Code : 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 DAY 
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE

Comment: I will fix the answer momentarily, but does it work when you say "CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS event_name ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MONTH ON COMPLETION PRESERVE" ?? I am not sure why this goes wrong for you, maybe the server version ?